# Making array from plist containing arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

I have this plist file

[image]

I need to make an array containing the arrays in the plist, so the array should have the values "numbers" & "colors" .

I tried this code but didn't work

```
- (NSString *) dataFilePath {
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"groups.plist"];
}

- (void) readPlist {
    NSString *path = [self dataFilePath];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *tempArray = [dict objectForKey:@"Root"];
    NSLog(@"%@", tempArray);
}
```

calling the readPlist from ViewDidLoad Method

any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
NSArray *tempArray = [dict objectForKey:@"Root"];
NSLog(@"%@", tempArray);
```

use

```
NSArray *tempArray = [dict allKeys];
NSLog(@"%@", tempArray);
```

Note that the order of the elements in the array is not defined, see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeys) of `NSDictionary`,

"Root" is just a label from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `groups.plist` file exists in the Documents Directory and not in your Bundle Directory.

Ensure that the `dict` is not nil and is actually a dictionary object as you expect.

Have you tried `[dict objectForKey:@"numbers"]`?

Comment: It is in my Documents Directory

Comment: This will make an array of One,Two and Three. I need to make an array containing the arrays in the plist, so the array will be "colors" and "numbers"

Comment: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[dict objectForKey:@"colors"], [dict objectForKey:@"numbers"], nil];

Comment: or NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];

Comment: I dont what the values of the numbers and colors array. i just want the app to read what arrays names are stored in the plist file and put that names in an array.

Comment: So the app should print "numbers" "colors" in the log.

Comment: NSArray *values = [dictionary allKeys];